# Android ScrollView not displaying child

Tags: android, scrollview

I am beginner to android. I stuck at a problem that scrollview not displaying full content.It is clipping some content.
Root element is constraint layout.
demo string resource contains lots of dummy text only. whole string is not displaying only part of string is displaying. please help me to solve this issue.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">


 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     android:id="@+id/mMainAppBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

     <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
         android:id="@+id/mMainToolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="@color/color_main_appbar"
         android:elevation="2dp"
         android:gravity="start"
         app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/color_main_bg"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:orientation="horizontal">

             <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
                 android:text="@string/app_name"
                 android:textAlignment="center"
                 android:textColor="@color/color_main_app_name"
                 android:textSize="22sp" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="end"
                 android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                 android:background="@color/color_main_bg"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/main_search_des"
                 android:foregroundGravity="right"
                 android:padding="8dp"
                 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_32" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

 <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:padding="10dp"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mMainAppBar">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/demo"
             />
     </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: is data not visibile when you are scrolling? Your xml seems fine

Comment: yes, data is not visible while scrolling

Comment: Want to clarify here, do you want only textview scrollable? or inside the scrollview > LinearLayout you are planning to take any other views also? If only TextView, you want to make it scrollable then there is a attribute of TextView,(No need to take scrollview) android:scrollbars="verticle" can work for you.

Comment: well, thanks for your reply. I solved it by setting layout_height of scrollview to 0dp and added a constraint  layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent". This trick work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above XML and it is showing all the text properly[image].

Check if you are setting any layout params inside your activity dynamically

Additionaly you can try using android:fitSystemWindows="true"

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mMainAppBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/demo"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Change the LinearLayout's and TextView's height to match_parent.

        `<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/demo"
            />
           </LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `paddingBottom` inside LinearLayout :

```
<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:padding="10dp"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mMainAppBar">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
      //android:paddingBottom="35dp"       Add here
            >
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/demo"
             />
     </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: it is still not working. if i change the height from wrapcontent to some value such as 500dp then it works with no problem.